# How to set image datasource in vaadin

Tags: java, user-interface, gwt, datasource, vaadin7

I have a horizontal split panel in which I want to show the image selected in combobox but unable to set the datasource  for image file.

```
FilesystemContainer container = new FilesystemContainer(new File("C:/myData/wallpaper"));
ComboBox box = new ComboBox("Documents", container);


@Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        setContent(box);

        com.vaadin.ui.HorizontalSplitPanel horizontalSplitPanel = new com.vaadin.ui.HorizontalSplitPanel();
        setContent(horizontalSplitPanel);
        horizontalSplitPanel.addComponent(box);
        //horizontalSplitPanel.addComponent(label);
        final Image image = new Image();
        horizontalSplitPanel.addComponent(image);
        box.addValueChangeListener(new ValueChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
                image.setData(event.getProperty().getValue());
                ///label.set//setPropertyDataSource( (Property) ImageIO.read((ImageInputStream) new TextFileProperty((File) event.getProperty().getValue())));

            }
        });

        box.setImmediate(true);
```

How can I set datasource for images.I'm very new in Vaadin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest this way:

```
@Override
public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    image.setSource(new FileResource((File)box.getValue()));
}
```